# Redux: implementing oauth

Tags: twitter, reactjs, oauth, redux

I am implementing user authentication using Twitter login and I would like to know how I can proceed.

My app is a universal app with react + redux. I set up the server side login logic using passport and [passport-twitter](http://passportjs.org/docs/twitter). When I go to `http://myApp/auth/twitter`, I obtain auth token from Twitter, persist it in db, and save the serialized user using express-session. I am redirected back to my app.

I now want to set up the client side logic. I think I need to store the user information in my redux store. But how can I do it? When I am redirected back to the app after a successful auth, how can I retrieve the user information?

Do I need to find the user info on the server side using something like `req.cookie`, send the initial state to the client, and rehydrate the user info on the client?

Comment: is it actual question?